# How to preserve newlines in VueJS when importing text from raw-loader and formatted using showdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, showdown, raw-loader

I am working on a website to show basic information about a sport. I have the (small) rulebook saved as `rulebook.md`. My project is using webpack and the latest vue-cli and yarn.

To import the rulebook I use `raw-loader` and pass the content to a Vue component called `markdown` that takes markdown and formats it with the `showdown` module.

`@/components/Markdown.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="markdown">
    {{ source }}
    {{ converted }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as showdown from 'showdown'
const converter = new showdown.Converter()
converter.setOption('simpleLineBreaks', true)

export default {
  name: 'markdown',
  props: ['source'],
  data () {
    return {
      converted: converter.makeHtml(this.source)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.markdown {
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

`@/views/punchies/Rulebook.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="punchies-rulebook" class="container">
    ...
    <markdown ... :source="source"></markdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Markdown from '@/components/Markdown.vue'
// eslint-disable-next-line
import source from 'raw-loader!@/views/punchies/misc/rulebook.md'

export default {
  name: 'rulebook',
  components: {
    'markdown': Markdown
  },
  data () {
    return {
      source
    }
  }
}
</script>

...
```

I have tried to set `showdown` to use line breaks and to tell CSS to render line breaks. Simply doing `console.log(source)` shows the rulebook without any line breaks in it. Upon searching this issue, the `raw-loader` github showed an issue where it is explained that `raw-loader` does preserve newlines.

Answer (score 0):

In Markdown.vue

```
<template>
    <p>{{source}}</p>
    <p v-html="converted"></p>
</template>
```

Comment: Yeah I want to end up using v-html, but I didn't in my example to demonstrate it is not the problem.